# Install Facebook Perl Module Debian

Tags: debian, perl

I'm getting an error

```
Can't locate Facebook.pm
```

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how to install the perl facebook module under debian.

Thanks

the full error is

```
Can't locate Facebook.pm in @INC (@INC contains: Plugins Modules . /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.cgi line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.cgi line 8.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"WWW::Facebook::API"?

try with (as root):

```
cpan install WWW::Facebook::API
```

You need 'cpan' installed for that (should be together with perl, but not sure for Debian)

Comment: Installed it but it's still giving the same thing :S